# Is there a Git Server Side Hook to put quota on repository sizes?

Tags: git

I searched around and found some related topics, but they were all related to limiting file sizes or concerns that there were quotas.

I built a Git server with Gitolite for a place for students to share course projects.   It all functions under one username on the server, git, with a wild card repositories "projects/Creator/[a-zA-Z0-9].*".   The repositories have WRITERS and READERS defined so the user can modify who can write and read their repository.

SSH key files are implemented so the user can just create a repository by:

git clone git@servername.edu:projects/bob/project1
git clone git@xervername.edu:projects/bob/someotherproj

and so on.  The "bob" folder is created the first time they do the git clone (it's their username).

My issue is that, being students, there will be abuse and I will need to limit the size of the "bob" folder.   Disk quotas don't work because all the folders and files are owned by git, and that's already limited.

I can probably re-engineer this to serve their projects from their Linux home folders and thus be able to use disk quotas, however, I'd rather not have to re-engineer this server now that I have it working.

Essentially, I was looking for a hook that did something like this rough shell script:

```
foldersize=`du -s $GITPATH/projects/$USERNAME`
if [ $foldersize > 250000 ]; then
     echo "Quota Exceeded"
     exit 1
fi
```

I understand there are server side hooks that can be written, I wanted to see if the wheel was already created before I started carving it out.   So, any hooks to limit repository size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The git `pre-receive` hook could be used to implement quotas.  From
the `githooks(5)` man page:

```
This hook is invoked by git-receive-pack on the remote repository,
which happens when a git push is done on a local repository. Just
before starting to update refs on the remote repository, the
pre-receive hook is invoked. Its exit status determines the success or
failure of the update.
```

So you would put your quota checking logic in this script and allow or
reject an incoming update depending on the result.  It would be your
job to actually perform quota management; there are a number of ways
to do this, the simplest being relying on your filesystem's support
for user quotas.

You could certainly use your `du` example, although as repositories grow in size this will impose a substantial delay (and i/o burden) for each update.  Caching the results from this script for some amount of time would probably help out, although the trade-off here is obviously that someone could then exceed their quota if they push an update before the cache has expired.

Depending on how your storage is organized, you could look into per-directory quotas for the git repositories (if your storage comes from something that supports this, like most enterprise fileservers), or using an LVM volume per repository (as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/100596/linux-quota-per-directory)).

Despite suggestions to the contrary, implementing quotas for a remote
repository is fairly common.  Most git-hosting services limit your
disk storage and will reject updates once you hit your limit.

Comment: According to man page, the pre-receive hook can be bypassed with an --noverify option...

The problem with filesystem support is that everything is under one UID with gitolite.   Guess I'll have to re-engineer the solution to use filesystem level user quotas and multiple accounts...and I thought I was almost done with this server...sigh.

Comment: That's why I mentioned per-directory quotas; this solves the "everything is one userid" problem.

Comment: Also note that `--no-verify` is an argument to `commit`, not to `push`.  A remote user cannot override your `pre-receive` hook.

Answer (score 0):

git doesn't have any functionality to implement quotas. I don't think there would be any sane way it could. What would happen when you hit your quota? You would no longer be able to commit, fetch updates from remote repositories, or any number of other maintenance type activities. Pretty much 'reach quota' === 'instant death to repository functionality'...

Comment: For what this would be used for, such a situation isn't a big deal.   If it were supporting development, then diskspace is cheaper than risking the repository.